# Clojure, atoms and refs

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I have a couple of question about refs and atom, and clojure reference types in general after reading [clojure programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013754.do) and mostly the question is related to this book.

**First:**

The books says about *coordination*, and it says "A coordinated operation is one where multiple actors must cooperate in order to yield correct results.". Does this mean if I have 3 fn `fn1`, `fn2`, and `fn3`, and each of them does some operation that possibly change the state of the reference (assuming it happens in each own `Thread`), it happens in a synchronous way in a chained operation? Something like, output of `fn1` is input of `fn2` and so on.

**Second:**

I cannot understand the difference between `refs` and `atoms`. The book says `refs` is for coordinated sync and `atoms` is for uncoordinated sync. Each of them (`refs` and `atoms`) has their own example, where `atoms` is used in such way where it is being operated by multiple function (1 atom 2 function), and multiple `refs` with 1 function. The book didn't give an example why we shouldn't or can't do the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Atoms allow multiple threads to apply transformations to a single value and guarantee the transformations are atomic. `swap!` takes the atom and a function expecting the current value of the atom. The result of calling that function with the current value is stored in the atom. multiple calls to `swap!` may interleave, but each call will run in isolation.
- Refs allow multiple threads to update multiple values in a co-ordinated way. All updates to all refs inside a `sync` will complete or none will. You MUST write your code such that transaction retries are catered for. There are a few potential performance tweaks, if you can relax the ordering of operations, which MAY reduce the chance of transaction retry (but don't guarantee it).

Answer (score 3):

Difference is really easy.

refs are operating under a transaction (similar to Databases transactions). Imagine a banking system. You can represent an account as a ref.
To transfer money, you start a Clojure STM transaction -via (dosync)-. Subtract X amount of money from **ref-1** and add that amount to account **ref-2**.
If something goes wrong, then Clojure STM will restart the operation.
Imagine there is no transaction. You subtracted X amount of money from **ref-1** and before you add that amount to **ref-2**, something went wrong in your system. Your customers will not be happy at all (if you aren't sued any way).

The Clojure STM is implemented as [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).

Atoms on the other hand don't need a transaction in place to operate. Atoms are convenient when there is no coordination. For example, a counter that increases the total number of a visited page in a web analytics system.

Have a look at [Clojure Refs](http://clojure.org/refs). It offers a lot of valuable information.